# Is there a full list of icc optimization flags somewhere?

Tags: icc

I don't have `icc` installed but I need a list of all compiler optimization flags. I tried Google and searching through their website documentation but I just cannot find anything.

I found a list of [all](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/682405) compiler options but I just need the optimization ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This page lists IC optimization flags - https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522802. This page doesn't show up with Google search. You need to search within https://software.intel.com

Answer (score 1):

Earlier versions of the `icc` `man` page listed all options grouped by purpose (preprocessor options, performance options, etc.). [Here's](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/icc.txt) a version from 2006.

Unfortunately, it seems as if they restructured all documentation and later incarnations of the `man` page just list all flags alphabetically ([here's](http://geco.mines.edu/guide/icc.html) a version from 2011) just like the webpage you linked describing v17. Other documentation (PDFs) I could find describing various other versions do the same so I doubt there is any other current list out there except for the full, alphabetical list which you already know.

Also, it seems as if `icc` is mostly compatible with `gcc` so it should support most `gcc` optimization flags (and probably silently drops unsupported ones).

Disclaimer: I don't use `icc` but this is what my own Google-Fu tells me.

Comment: `icc --help` will still show the grouped flags as it seems?